# codemirror option from a variable

Tags: php, textarea, codemirror

with codemirror 2 I've got some options like lineNumbers, gutter and so on... I am wondering how to set those reading a variable like:

```
var ln = 'true';
editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea.get(0), {
        height : "140px",
        lineWrapping : true,
        lineNumbers : ln,
        gutter : true,
        mode: 'application/xml',    
    }
```

The idea, is that you fill out a php form with options you wish to use with codemirror and then cm is building the textarea with these options.

lineNumbers : ln doesnt seem to work... it has no affect on the textarea

how can I get vars to set options before the codemirror is loaded?

Comment: did you forget to ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

Your options can indeed be built ahead of time and passed in. The only thing wrong with your above example is the variable ln has been set to the string 'true' rather than the boolean value true.

```
var ln = true; //not string 'true';
var options = {
    height : "140px",
    lineWrapping : true,
    lineNumbers : ln,
    gutter : true,
    mode: 'application/xml',  
}
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea.get(0), options);
```